# Heap or stack for creating objects?

Tags: c++, object, stack, heap-memory

I have this program which creates "Computer components" and stores it in a vector and writes the objects to a file.
If i create the objects on the stack and pass the memory address to the vector i get an error
if i create the objects on the heap and pass the pointer to the vector it works just fine "Component is a absract base class" and "CPU is a derived class from Component" Can someone explain why this is?

```
vector<Component*>components;
CPU x;
CPU*y = new CPU();

components.push_back(&x) // results in debug error
components.push_back(y) // works fine.

writeTofile(components);
```

Comment: What is the "debug error" you get? Also what is `Object` and how is it related to `CPU`?

Comment: To get a meaningful answer, you should provide [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean), i.e. a minimal complete verifiable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing this

`CPU x;
components.push_back(&x);`

you create a local object on the stack and push the address of it to the vector. When the function goes out of scope, your local object is not alive anymore, and its address in the vector is invalid.

Comment: It does exist. Here `x` is a temporary object. If its lifetime is less than the lifetime of `components`, it's an error. If it is not the case, please elaborate on your example, answering the question of @Botje

Comment: If i would declare `static CPU x` the problem would be gone aswell?

Comment: Which C++ book are you using @Greg

Comment: Yes, but this is not a good way to manage memory. The c++-way is either just to use `vector<object>` for non-inherited types or `vector<shared_ptr<object>>` with `make_shared` for virtual hierarchies.